# Express and node send error messages to handlebars view

Tags: node.js, express

How do I output validation errors to the view for the email `unique: true` option?  In my handlebars view I am getting `errors` passed from `var errors = req.validationErrors();` and displaying it in the view which is working. but the email validation for uniqueness is going to `user.save((err)` and is just being sent to the console.  The validation is working correctly, no user is created if there is a duplicate email.  I'm just trying to send the error message to the view.  Can I do a `req.check` for `unique: true` ?

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

my createUser.handlebars view

```
{{#if errors}}
  <section class="errors">
    <ul>
      {{#each errors}}
        <li>{{this.msg}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </section>
{{/if}}
```

the createUser function

```
module.exports.createUser =
    (req, res, next) => {

        let user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });


        req.check('email', 'Invalid email').isEmail(); 
        req.check('password', "Passwords must match").isLength({min: 6}).equals(req.body.passwordConfirmation);

        var errors = req.validationErrors();  // save any error messages

        // check if there are any errors
        if (errors) {
            req.session.errors = errors; 

            req.session.success = false;
            return res.redirect('/users/new'); 
        } else {
            req.session.success = true;
        }
        // save the user
        user.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error : %s ", err);
            }
            // set the session messages back to null and redirect
            req.session.success = null;    
            req.session.errors = null;                    
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you're using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) for validation. The issue is you're mixing two things: form validation and database constraints.

Uniqueness is not an intrinsic property of a data item and it cannot be checked independently of the entire set.

You can only check for uniqueness using a call to the database. If your database schema defines this attribute/column as unique, then trying to store it will throw an error (at least in SQL-based databases and MongoDB).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom validation check like this

```
check('email').custom(value => {
        return userController.findByEmail(value).then( user => {
            if(user){
                return Promise.reject('this email already exists')
            }
        })
})
```

i write this in Router and define function in Controller

```
async findByEmail(email){
    const candidate = await User.findOne({ where: {username}})
    if(candidate){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```